# Symofny -'password' cannot be null

Tags: php, api, symfony, passwords

I have implemented function to check my password length in register api call like..

```
if($password){
    $this->validatePassword($password);
    }
```

from other api call..

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    if (strlen($password) < 6)
    {
        throw new PasswordLength('Password must be minimum 6 characters long!');
    }
}
```

and in my postman I am not returning an empty field but I keep getting error

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null

Comment: And what do you want? Do a debug - output password value somewhere and check.

Comment: ´$user->setPlainPassword($password);´ probably sets the 'plain_password' field and not 'password' ... usually, 'password' is the encoded password string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In symfony, the `plainPassword` field is purely used to carry the users 'new' password into a method that would encode it and set it to `password`.

After the `password` field is populated, then the `plainPassword` field is blanked so that no plain text credentials are saved to the db.  This is done by calling the implemented `eraseCredentials` method (found in the required [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html)).  Or, you can make the `plainPassword` method non-persistent in the user class.

Have a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html) at the docs to see how to go about it all.

The docs show an extract from what should be a user manager utility class. Use this to set and update passwords as well as creating new users.

Theres a more complete explination [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html#registration-password-max) where the whole process is explained from end-to-end.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
if($password){
    $this->validatePassword($password);
}

$user->setPassword($password);
```